# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer | linux |ssh is working

Tags: ssh, reset

When I am doing ssh user@ipaddress it't working fine but I am using this command `ssh -t -p2222 user@myserverip remoteuser@remoteip`.

That time it is showing error `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.
I am ablt to telnet
host.deny and allow file I checked no rules

[image]

Comment: Hi ans welcome to AskUbuntu. What's the intention of this command? Are you perhaps missing an `ssh` between the two user@host specifiers? It looks a little like you're attempting to use `myserverip` as a jump host ...

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code